# How can I apply a circular smooth indicator border like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to know how to add a border like this, using  [`smooth_page_indicator`](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator) package

[image]

**My Code:**

```
             SmoothPageIndicator(
                controller: pageController,
                count: containers.length,
                effect: const ScaleEffect(
                  scale: 1,
                  dotHeight: 9,
                  dotWidth: 9,
                  dotColor: Colors.white,
                  activePaintStyle: PaintingStyle.stroke,
                  strokeWidth: 2,
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there in their documentation. I hope this helps and you can change the color you want.

```
 ScaleEffect(
   scale: 1.5,
   dotHeight: 10,
   dotWidth: 10,
   dotColor: Colors.blue,
   activeDotColor: Colors.blue,
   activePaintStyle: PaintingStyle.stroke,
   strokeWidth: 2
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I searched a lot actually but could not find it.

Comment: pleasure helping peer developers :) Can you upvote the answer :D

Comment: Can you please tell me where did you find it?

Comment: I read their example code fully and then came up with the need you had.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **CustomizableEffect** for ultimate control

```
       CustomizableEffect(
          dotDecoration: DotDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFA4A1A1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
          ),
          activeDotDecoration: DotDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFF272522),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
            dotBorder: DotBorder(
              color: Color(0xFFE7A356),
              width: 2,
              padding: 3,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

**Output:**

[image: Sample output]